Is registering to vote in the US automatically counted as a vote for that party?
If a voter in the USA Presidential election Registers to Vote providing a political preference, is their Registered Vote automatically counted as a Vote for that particular party?

It wouldn't be a secret voting then. Did you by chance search for the answer before?

Yes, I did search. I thought you had secret ballots in the US. I read that Elon Musk is paying people to register Republican. I didn't know why he'd do this if he can't be sure they will vote for Trump, so the answer below confused me. It removed the concept of a secret ballot. Why do 'some' States have different rules 'primaries' even though it's still for a 'federal' election?Australia has same rules for Local, State & Federal elections. We have Compulsory, Preferential voting.

Somehow in the US, organizing elections is a state privilege, so rules differ. Probably grown historically.

@WendyMaxwell I think there's a misunderstanding on what parties are in the US. Political parties are self organized private organizations based on self interests that lobby together to increase their voting power, not public organizations enshrined in the constitution. So primaries aren't real elections in the way that local/state/federal elections are. They are a gathering of party members to decide who the party should back as a whole and not split their votes between two similar candidates. Party registration is mostly so other parties can't sabotage the primaries of others.

What do you mean "counted as a Vote for that particular party?"  Registration is not voting, and when you vote, you vote for a candidate not a party.

Musk is not paying people to register to vote, or vote, which would be illegal.  He's paying them to sign a petition.  https://www.reuters.com/world/us/elon-musks-1-million-election-giveaway-tests-limits-election-law-2024-10-21/  And they could pocket his $ and vote Harris.

federal != national

@ItalianPhilosopher - ...but they can't get the promised $ if they aren't registered voters. So it is indirectly paying people to register to vote. Certainly violates the spirit of the law, but if it violates the letter of the law is going to be an issue the US Justice system gets to work out. I know when I was doing a voter registration drive, it was drilled into me that we aren't allowed to pay people, nor are we allowed to suggest what party they should register with. If you wanna stilt things, you do it by your choice of places to hold the drive. (Gun show or Public Housing Project)

@T.E.D. I don't disagree, I was just correcting the OP's interpretation of what Musk is doing:  he's not "paying people to register Republican".  He's skirting the law, for sure.  Whether or not it's legal, dunno, but I also doubt it's that obviously illegal that a court won't have to decide.  Remember the purpose of the 2+2=? questions on sweepstakes style competition? Making it not a gambling situation.  I suppose signing a petition is intended the same way.  FWIW, I upvoted the question, it's a bit naive, but only to someone unfamiliar with US voting procedures.

@uberhaxed However, political parties hold special privileges in states: recognition as a party, followed by a primary election or caucus is a specific avenue for ballot access, for specific offices recognized as partisan. Otherwise, a candidate must usually submit a certain number of signed petitions to appear, be an incumbent, or in certain typically municipal offices, nominated by an existing board/committee.

@WendyMaxwell, Musk is a pretty smart guy. I am sure he does not assume that everyone who signs his petition will do so sincerely.  And as it's being reported, the petition doesn't even express support for a particular candidate.  It sounds like it's structured to be more palatable to conservative voters, though, and I imagine that Musk expects that despite the inevitable defections, it will have a net influence favorable to his political objectives.  It doesn't even matter for that purpose whether any of the money goes to defectors.

"Registered Vote" isn't really a thing, registration and voting are two separate things (though connected).

@uberhaxed Political parties aren't completely private organizations. Although they aren't run by the government, court cases have found them to be so integral to the electoral system that some restrictions that normally apply to the government also apply to them. For instance, they aren't allowed to restrict membership to a particular race.

@Acccumulation I don't think any private organization can attempt to restrict membership, employment, or patronage by race, get sued in court and then win so that statement makes no sense. Famously, if it even looks like you're restricting by race even if it isn't (e.g. mortgages pre-2008) then you can't do it.

@ItalianPhilosopher Not that paying for signing a petition is morally any better. In particular when it amounts to signing a paper that lawmakers may or may not acknowledge and that is about not making changes to amendmends that are by their very nature of constitutinal amendment very hard to modify to begin with (e.g., way harder than overturning Roe v Wade)

No. US presidential elections are free and secret. US citizens who are registered to vote are free to vote for any candidate they want, or not vote at all. Regardless of which party affiliation they stated when they registered. And due to the secrecy of the vote, it is impossible to prove if a voter voted for "their" party candidate or not.
However, in some states, the stated party affiliation decides if a voter is eligible to vote in the primary election for a party. The primary elections happen about half a year before the presidential election and decide who exactly is going to run as a presidential candidate for each party.
Also, parties know who registered for them and where they live. US election campaigns usually focus more on mobilizing the own supporters instead of convincing undecided voters. So when you register for a specific party, you can expect to be targeted by campaign advertising for that specific party for the rest of your life while the other parties will mostly ignore you.

You can change your party registration in these states that require it for the primary.  It's just that you cannot change the registered party recorded on primary day or immediately preceding the primary day.  If they allowed you to change parties on primary day, their "closed primary" system would essentially be the same as an "open primary" system (which is not to be confused with a jungle primary).

"campaigns usually focus more on mobilizing the own supporters instead of convincing undecided voters." It's just the opposite in New Hampshire. We are currently 30% Dem, 31% Rep and 39% Undeclared. Parties spend the most on direct mail to our Undeclared voters, who are most often not undecided, but choose not to affiliate with either party on a permanent basis. To vote in the primary, we join a party at the polls for as long as it takes to fill out a ballot, cast our vote, then immediately disenroll if that is our choice and become undeclared again before leaving the polls.

It's worth noting that voting was not secret in the US until the late 19th century. I don't think there's anything in the constitution about this.  AFAICT the Voting Rights Act is the only thing that requires the right to secret voting.

@JimmyJames - No, the constitution doesn't have much to say about how states conduct their elections. Several amendments did address ballot access (so if you do have an election, you can't discriminate on who gets to vote), but for example I believe its still quite constitutional for state legislatures to just appoint their presidential electors without consulting The People at all. The 17th Amendment does require a popular vote for Senators, but not for Presidential/VP electors.

@T.E.D Right. I'm pretty sure they could have state senators appoint the electors.  There was a short period of time that was actually the way some states did it initially.  But it's also why states can have 'winner takes all' appointments and is also how the National Popular Vote Interstate Compact would work.

I wonder how many percent of voters are registered as party voters approximately in the US?

@NoDataDumpNoContribution If you wonder that and can't easily find the answer, then you could open a new question about that.

@robertbristow-johnson not all states require party registration. When I vote in a primary, I specify which party's ballot I want at the polling location, because my state doesn't have party registration at all. I've voted in the primary for both major parties in my state, though only one at a time.

No. Party registration actually has surprisingly little impact at all.
Political parties in the USA are usually allowed their own (state-run) elections before the general election. This is called a primary election. In this election, only candidates from that party appear on the ballot, and the election is to decide which candidate the party will put forth in the real election, called the general election.
The only effect registering with a party usually has to you as a voter is that it affects which party's ballot is handed to you during a primary election.*
In a general election, like the USA will have this year on November 5th, all registered voters (who bother to show up) are handed the same ballot, and are free to vote for whomever they like. The ballots do helpfully tell you which candidates were put forth by which party, in case you care about that kind of thing.

Now the unasked question: "Then what good will Musk's voter drive shenanigans do for anyone?"
Perhaps none. Most registered voters stay home most elections in the USA, so it seems unlikely that a particular person who registers to vote motivated mainly by Musks' giveaway will bother to show up to vote when they haven't before.
On the other hand, the amount of those people who would have voted before would be 0%, so any actual voters this makes are extra votes. The pledge he makes them sign is designed to be sort of a poison pill for non-Conservatives, but still there's nothing stopping that 63% of the population from just lying in an attempt to be eligible for Musk's money. So while he might induce a lot of people to register this way, its uncertain how much that will help his intended party.
I'd expect a normal Republican voter registration drive, carried out at an Evangelical Church, Country Music Concert, Nascar venue, Gun Show, etc. to be far more effective on a per-capita basis. However, if people get really excited by his money and millions register, what little effect he has could end up large in the aggregate.

* - This is the traditional scenario. Every state has its own election laws, and within the states usually the state party gets to decide who can vote in their primaries. Some states let voters ask for whichever party's ballot they want during primaries. My own state (Oklahoma) the Democratic party allows independent voters to request a Democratic ballot, but the Republican party does not. There are lots more complicated ways states may choose to run their primaries. Still, if you receive a Republican primary ballot for a primary election (by whatever rules the state followed to give you that Republican ballot) it will have only Republican candidates on it.

Since I know someone else will comment, I will add that if you live in a strict primary state, and other parties aren't very competitive where you live, often voters find the only way to get to vote at all for most offices in most elections is to register with the dominant party so they can vote in its primary. All other parties have trouble recruiting candidates, they may not have a primary ballot, and there may not be any opposition candidates in the general (so no vote there either). So in that case, yes its a big deal which party you register with.

But since party registration has little meaning except for which primary you vote in, there's little downside to registering for the party other than the one you politically align with. The only problem would be if there's two positions where only one party will field candidates, and they're different parties. But when there's a dominant party, they usually field all the nominees to uncontested races.

Never mind that. The real problem is that you can't vote in your party's primary for President.

"Most registered voters stay home most elections in the USA" Wrong. 70% of registered voters voted in the last 6 presidential elections. This represented 60%, the majority, of eligible voters. It is true there are many off-year elections that nobody cares about, e.g. purely municipal polls consisting of who's going to be on the parks and rec district board, but that's not what's going on here.

@Barmar Except that cements the control of the one party. Someone has to represent another party if there's ever going to be change.

@prosfilaes Getting nominees to run in the other party is a separate problem. If there actually were candidates who had a chance to win, then voters wouldn't feel the need to vote in the other primary.

@user71659 - That was a record high, and thus says nothing about "most registered voters in most elections.". Try this link instead.

Isn't the real aim getting of the stunt to get publicity and people to talk about it?

@NoDataDumpNoContribution - I'm going with "no".

So then do you go with "yes" on, it's an ineffective attempt to influence the election?

@NoDataDumpNoContribution - Not sure. It would be interesting for someone to study. Like go over his signatures, cross check with voting registration records to see who registered recently before (or after) signing, and then check their subsequent voting records. Perhaps exit poll some of them too.

I would recommend editing the part about closed primaries. Closed primaries aren't typical at all. Only 12 of 50 states use closed primaries like what are described in the answer here (i.e. ones that only allow you to vote in the party you're registered for.) Some states don't even have any official party registration as part of the voter registration process (you can still go join the party itself if you want, but that doesn't affect your voting rights at all.)

@reirab - Edited the footnote a bit. For the record, The WP page is a bit out of date, but according to it there were until recently 13 states with Closed primaries (14 counting DC), 16 more that are semi-closed, and 14 that are completely open. I believe the discrepancy is Oklahoma, which should be moved from closed to semi-closed (or semi-semi-closed, or closed with an asterix, since the only other ballot you can get is a Democratic one, and only if you're registered Independent).

"all registered voters (who bother to show up) are handed the same ballot" Nitpick: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_-uJl_Db4Rw

@Acccumulation - Kind of a lame nitpick. First off, obviously you have to be there in-person to be handed something. The word "handed" implies a personal interaction. Secondly, it isn't even a fully-covered "well actually", because people (at least in my state) can get their ballots mailed to them if they ask for that. So its totally possible to vote without ever "bothering to show up".

@T.E.D. It's not clear what you think my nitpick is, but you're almost certainly wrong. The order of the candidates are shuffled so that each candidate comes first on the same number of ballots. As a result, people don't all get the same ballot. Also, as long as I'm nitpicking, the phrase "in-person" takes a hyphen when it's used as an adjective, but when used as an adverb as it is in your comment, it's "in person".
